# Find a links by Regular expressions - Java

Tags: java, regex

I wanna find a links on webpage(saved in String variable) by regexp. Especially defined by tag:"`<a href=”link”></a>`". (Starts with `<a href=` and ends `</a>`) How should looks like this regex, and what should I type into ??? field. TIA ;)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sourceOfHtml = "Some html code of webpage with links";


    regexChecker("???", sourceOfHtml);


}

public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2check){

    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);

    Matcher regexmatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2check);

    while(regexmatcher.find()){
        if(regexmatcher.group().length()!=0){
            System.out.println(regexmatcher.group().trim());

        }


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex for this. [Do use an HTML parser.](http://jsoup.org/)

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(sourceOfHtml);
Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex :)

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```